# Google Apps Script でGoogleスプレッドシートの関数を利用する方法はありませんか？

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Google Apps ScriptからGoogleスプレッドシートの関数を利用する方法はありませんか？
Excelマクロでいうところの、Application.WorksheetFunctionを探していたのですが、
見当たらず質問しています。
ご存知の方が居たら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: `Google Apps Scriptから でGoogleスプレッドシートの関数を利用`について、`Googleスプレッドシートの関数`が["Google スプレッドシートの関数リスト"](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273)の関数の場合、残念ながら直接Google Apps Scriptの中でそれらの関数を使用することはできません。ただし、間接的に使用することは可能です。間接的に使用する場合は、一度スクリプトを使って使用したい関数をセルへ配置した後に結果を取得することで実現できます。あるいは、使用したい関数をGoogle Apps Scriptを使って作成する方法もありと思われます。これらが期待した方向でない場合は謝罪致します。

Comment: ありがとうございました。やはり、一度シートで計算した値を取得する方法しかなさそうですね。

Comment: GAS側からそれを使用しないとならない理由ってなんですか？
その理由を書くことで、シート関数によらない別の回答が得られるかも知れません。